# Datatables warning while using server side processing

Tags: asp.net, datatables

I am using the [datatables plugin](http://www.datatables.net), and everything works good until I add enable server side processing.

All the rows from the table appear together on the page, no css and borders and no search query works.

> "DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error."

I am simply using a SQL data source which is being bound to a gridview.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#GridView1').GridviewFix({ header: "headerStyle", row: "rowStyle", footer: "footerStyle" }).dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "WebForm4.aspx",
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
           "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
            }});
```

I am using firebug to see my JSON Data but there is no JSON data being detected either by firebug or fiddler.

Do I have to convert the sql data to JSON format or something?
What must I do ? I have tried to post on their website but no luck.

Everyone with the similar problem sees to get a JSON response from the server but in my case , there is none.

Comment: The most important part is the return of the JSON from the server. Edit your question to include that method, and the **values you see when debugging the server side call**.

Comment: @p.campbell
There is no json being returned from the server. As i said , there is no JSON tab appearing in the firebug and the JSON tabs for client and server are empty for Fiddler.So there is no JSON values being returned.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm saying. Debug your server side issue to determine why no JSON is being returned. Edit your question to show what's happening on the server side.

Comment: @p.campbell
the c# code is plain and simple.  Theres not really any code. I just have a rowdatabound event in my C# file.
I am simply using a sqldatasource wizard for my gridview.

Comment: @p.campbell
This is my debug for datatables.
http://debug.datatables.net/anaret

Answer (score 1):

DataTables is expecting a specific formatted [JSON Server Response](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) object. Your comment responses seem to indicate that you are not constructing the necessary response object on the server.

I have a full sample implementation of using [Server-Side Paging w/ DataTablea](http://www.woodcp.com/2012/02/server-side-paging-with-petapoco-and-datatables/) on my blog with associate code available on [github](https://github.com/tawman/PetaPocoPage)

It would help to see your server-side code if you are in fact generating the proper JSON response.